# How to Manually Change the Request URL of an HttpServletRequest

Tags: servlets, netflix-zuul

I have a Zuul server running in front of a web server. A part of the web server that I am unable to change is calling the method `getRequestURL()` on my `HttpServletRequest` object. 
As part of a pre-routing filter on the Zuul server I would like to modify the `requestURL` of this `HttpServletRequest`. How can I do that?

My code that I'm working from looks like this so far:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
StringBuffer originalURL = request.getRequestURL(); // Returns original url
// ...modifying the requestURL
StringBuffer newURL = request.getRequestURL(); // Returns new url
```

Comment: AFAIK not possible - Zuul and the "web server" are running separately, in different JVMs, Zuul receives the HTTP request from browser, does its magic, and sends a *new* HTTP request to the "web server " (servlet). The servlet processes the new request from Zuul, not the request from browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Jozef seems to be correct: it does not appear to be possible to modify the request URL in this way. This documentation  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html also doesn't show any methods that would seem to allow it either.